# How do I get my product details in my magento 1.9 including product reviews etc

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I've been learning **magento1** recently, but I don't know much about **how magento gets product details**

I just want to get some necessary information about the product and some of the properties I defined, I'll change it again. If you can get your help, this will be very good.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you got the product id then you can get details of a product by using the following method in Magento.

```
<?php
   $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $_product = $obj->load($product_id); // Enter your Product Id in $product_id
    // get Product's name
    echo $_product->getName();
    //get product's short description
    echo $_product->getShortDescription();
    //get Product's Long Description
    echo $_product->getDescription();
    //get Product's Regular Price
    echo $_product->getPrice();
    //get Product's Special price
    echo $_product->getSpecialPrice();
    //get Product's Url
    echo $_product->getProductUrl();
    //get Product's image Url
    echo $_product->getImageUrl();

    $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')
                    ->load($_product->getId());

if ($summaryData['rating_summary']):?>
    <div class="ratings">
        <div class="rating-box">
            <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $summaryData['rating_summary']; ?>%"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: $summaryData['rating_summary']  There is nothing inside, I try to print and get null

Comment: @Calvin that means there is no rating summary for that product.

Comment: @Calvin, If my answer solves or help in your concern then there is green right tick mark, hit that tickmark for right answer that will help future readers.